# Wait for Firebase document to be available before loading with Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs

I have the following property on one of my services.  It watches the Angular Auth state, then takes the User ID and returns an observable of the Firestore document matching the User's ID.

```
this.$userDoc = this.auth.authState.pipe(switchMap(user => {
  if (user) {
    return this.fs.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges({ idField: "userID" });
  }
  else {
    return of(undefined);
  };
}));
```

The user document is very important and is required for me to determine what menu items to show and such like.  As a result I'd like to ensure that there is a value for this document available prior to loading the "main" component after log-in.  I understand that a Route Resolver is a way to achieve this, but ultimately I'd like the service to be the source of the data, such that my components can subscribe to ValueChanges observable.

Is there a way for a resolver to "ask" my service if there is a Document existing on the observable before continuing the route activation?

Comment: You could use a route guard to prevent loading of the component if the data hasn't yet loaded.

Comment: Hi, that was my question really..... what should I do in my route guard to check the state of the observable - note as it is firebase, the $userDoc is an observable not just the user data.

Comment: You might find some useful info [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#preventing-unauthorized-access) on how to setup your route guards. The guard methods also return `Observable<boolean>` and `Promise<boolean>` in case you're waiting for an asynchronous action.